# Automate ALM QC's data extraction with an API & Python

Tags: testing, alm, hp-quality-center, microfocus

I want to automate the extraction of my data relating to the tests carried out on ALM Quality Center, and I was wondering if it was possible via an API?

In particular, I want to recover, in Excel format, data such as the number of successful tests, the number of failed tests...

Thank you in advance for your response!

I'm new to the tool so for now I'm just reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate towards QC REST API, that is possible, but you need to check:

Which QC version are you using. The QC-10 is different from QC-12 or QC-15 or latest 17.

Once you know the version, I hardly encourage you to have a look at the REST API material from Micro Focus. That will explain mostly what you need.

First steps will be to login (saving Cookies and special TAGS in a python dictionary) and to create a session where to send all your subsequent requests.

Modify Test Lab / Test Plan / Defects / Test Instances....everything will be possible towards REST API.

It is possible then to collect all parameter from a Test Plan/Test Lab ´results and as well with python to create/archive modify into an excel (there are plenty of modules as well for that).
As said with the information above, that is maximum I can suggest. Hope that will help a bit. I have used QC for a decade and always automated over REST API...much simpler and quick accessing/reporting data. You can use Python or Java for REST scripts...I prefer python. Have a great one!